# Oracle Linux 7 graphical.target service don't start automatically

Tags: gnome, upgrade, oracle-linux

I was upgraded a oracle linux from version 6.10 to 7.6
after finish operation graphical interface don't tart automatically and must be start manually with **startx**.
when get status of service show this:

```
[root@TestDB ~]# systemctl status graphical.target
● graphical.target - Graphical Interface
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active since Tue 2023-12-05 19:07:26 +03; 18h ago
     Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
```

**vendor preset : disabled**
even after ENABLE that :

```
[root@TestDB ~]# systemctl enable graphical.target

[root@TestDB ~]# systemctl status graphical.target
● graphical.target - Graphical Interface
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active since Tue 2023-12-05 19:07:26 +03; 18h ago
     Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
```

of course run level is 5:

```
#runlevel
N 5
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one way to disable graphical login, and apparently whoever did this did not use the expected way (which would translate to setting the default target to `multi-user.target` on OEL 7.x).

The `gdm` service might have been disabled. If so, enable and start it:

```
systemctl enable gdm.service
systemctl start gdm.service
```

If `gdm` is running, it might be trying to start the X11 server but failing. Checking the existence and timestamps of `/var/log/gdm.log` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` might be informative, and reading those logs might identify the actual problem in starting the X11 server, if there is any.